# How to Reduce Dropdown Option height?

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

[image]

I want to reduce this option hight and it should be coming scroll And Also please tell me is there possible to without any scripts.

Comment: add your code and working `fiddle`

Answer (score 0):

Please add your code here, then anyone can help you and you will understand.

You have to set `max-height` in that container and add `overflow: scroll` in css. Than I hope you will get solution.